# Xamarin Android App error when authenticating

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to add authentication to my Xamarin Android application. I'm using the following as a guide: https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2#integrate-microsoft-identity-and-the-microsoft-graph-into-a-xamarin-forms-app-using-msal

The sample works fine when I try to run it in the Android Emulator from Visual Studio: it pops up a login page and, when finished, returns to the application. However, when I try to do the same in my application, the application breaks on external code (I get the "The application is in break mode" page in Visual Studio).

In the code below, the OnActivityResult in MainActivity is called (I have a breakpoint), but control is never returned to the line after AcquireTokenInteractive in ContinuousScanPage.

The relevant sections of code are as follows (irrelevant code has been removed for the sake of brevity):

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected async override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        App.ParentWindow = this;
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        AuthenticationContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationContinuationEventArgs(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private string _deviceId;

    public string DeviceId { get => _deviceId; internal set => _deviceId = value; }
    public IPublicClientApplication PCA { get; set; } = null;
    public static object ParentWindow { get; set; }
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    public App()
    {
        Settings settings = Settings.Get<Settings>();

        InitializeComponent();
        DeviceId = CrossDeviceInfo.Current.Id;

        PCA = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(settings.AuthClientId)
            .WithRedirectUri($"msal{settings.AuthClientId}://auth")
            .Build();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Pages.ContinuousScanPage(CaptureType.MusterIn));
    }
}
```

ContinuousScanPage.xaml.cs

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ContinuousScanPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly App _app;

    public CaptureType CaptureType { get; }

    public ContinuousScanPage(CaptureType captureType)
    {
        CaptureType = captureType;

        InitializeComponent();
        _app = (App)Application.Current;
     }

    public static bool IsPageFirstLoad = true;
    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        if (IsPageFirstLoad)
        {
            IsPageFirstLoad = false;
            await SignIn();
            BindingContext = this;
        }

        base.OnAppearing();
    }

    private async Task SignIn()
    {
        Settings settings = Settings.Get<Settings>();

        AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
        IEnumerable<IAccount> accounts = await _app.PCA.GetAccountsAsync();
        try
        {
            IAccount firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();
            authResult = await _app.PCA.AcquireTokenSilent(settings.AuthScope, firstAccount).ExecuteAsync();
            await RefreshUserDataAsync(authResult.AccessToken);
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
        {
            authResult = await _app.PCA.AcquireTokenInteractive(settings.AuthScope)
                .WithParentActivityOrWindow(App.ParentWindow)
                .ExecuteAsync();
            await RefreshUserDataAsync(authResult.AccessToken);
        }
    }

    public async Task RefreshUserDataAsync(string token)
    {
        _app.AccessToken = token;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to updating the application w/your clientId and redirectUri, you also have to make sure you have the following in the Android manifest:

```
<activity android:name="microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="msal{client_id}" android:host="auth" />
         </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In the `android:scheme` you need to include your clientId. Hopefully, this will resolve your issue (replace the [client_id](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2/blob/msal3x/UserDetailsClient/UserDetailsClient.Droid/Properties/AndroidManifest.xml#L12) in the manifest w/your own)

Comment: Actually, I do have that: I just didn't include it for the sake of brevity

Comment: @JeffHornby I just tried the sample w/the latest version of MSAL, and am not having the same issue. I also used my own tenant, trying to replicate what you are doing as well, but am not hitting the same issue. Can you provide logs?